# How to get time for splashscreen

Tags: java, android

How to get time for splashcreen?
I want to add about 15 second time? How can I integrate it into the code?
For example, to direct activity after about 15 seconds.

```
package com.trees.activities;

import android.app.Activity;

import android.content.Intent;

import android.content.SharedPreferences;

import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainSlider extends Activity{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        SharedPreferences settings=getSharedPreferences("prefs",0);
        boolean firstRun=settings.getBoolean("firstRun",false);
        if(firstRun==false)//if running for first time
        //Splash will load for first time
        {
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor=settings.edit();
            editor.putBoolean("firstRun",true);
            editor.commit();
            Intent i=new Intent(MainSlider.this,MaterialIntro.class);
            startActivity(i);
            finish();
        }
        else
        {
            Intent a=new Intent(MainSlider.this,MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(a);
            finish();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you want your users to wait 15 seconds before they can use your app?? Instant uninstall from me

Comment: 15 second for example.

Comment: [Splash Screens Are Evil, Don't Use Them](http://cyrilmottier.com/2012/05/03/splash-screens-are-evil-dont-use-them/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HOW TO: [Simple spash screen](http://www.anddev.org/simple_splash_screen-t811.html)

First you need to define the spash screen in your layout.xml file

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent">

          <ImageView android:id="@+id/splashscreen" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                  android:src="@drawable/splash"
                  android:layout_gravity="center"/>

          <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Hello World, splash"/>

  </LinearLayout>
```

And your activity:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;

public class Splash extends Activity {

/** Duration of wait **/
private final int SPLASH_DISPLAY_LENGTH = 1000;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    setContentView(R.layout.splashscreen);

    /* New Handler to start the Menu-Activity 
     * and close this Splash-Screen after some seconds.*/
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run() {
            /* Create an Intent that will start the Menu-Activity. */
            Intent mainIntent = new Intent(Splash.this,Menu.class);
            Splash.this.startActivity(mainIntent);
            Splash.this.finish();
        }
    }, SPLASH_DISPLAY_LENGTH);
}
}
```